# Dockerized joomla site with Apache2 as proxy, problems loading .js files

Tags: apache, docker, joomla

I'm moving a joomla web site initially installed under one server (say `SERVER_1`) as a web application under Apache 2 to another server (`SERVER_2`).

In this second server, the joomla site is installed as a docker container (actually two docker containers, the second one running a mysql instance). The joomla contiainer exposes port `8081`, and if I access via browser `http://<SERVER_2_IP>:8081/` the site works perfectly.

Now I try to change the DNS setting on my provider for a name `www.example.com` from the old to the new server's IP. Moreover, on `SERVER_2` I have an apache2 which I use to act as a proxy, forwarding requests to `www.example.com` to the correct port 8081. The following is the virtual host definition file for apache2 (I am not an expert of apache2 configuration, just copied this from configuration mapping to other containerized applications, non joomla ones, which work fine).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName www.example.com

        <LocationMatch "^/">
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
        </LocationMatch>

        ErrorLog /path/to/folder/under/home/example.error.log
        LogLevel trace1
        CustomLog /path/to/folder/under/home/example.access.log combined

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that when accessing the site from the browser at `http://www.example.com` though the site is found it seems that styles are broken. If I check the browser console I see a list of errors like the following (*note: I translated thte message from the Italian, so the actual error message might be different*).

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8081/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js”.
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8081/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js”.
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8081/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js”.
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8081/media/system/js/caption.js”.
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8081/media/system/js/mootools-core.js”.
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8081/media/system/js/core.js”.
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8081/media/system/js/mootools-more.js”.
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8081/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js”.
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8081/templates/whalesafe/javascript/md_stylechanger.js”.
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8081/templates/whalesafe/javascript/hide.js”.
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8081/templates/whalesafe/javascript/respond.src.js”.
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8081/media/sourcecoast/js/jq-bootstrap-1.8.3.js”.
```

The problem seems to be related to the joomla code trying to access javascript files from `localhost` instead of `www.example.com` but I have no further idea about how to address this.

As I wrote, if I acess the browser using the `IP/PORT` (my local machine is under the same network as the server, so I can access the port 8081 directly from here) everything is ok, as was ok when accessing the site on the old server.

**edit**: just to add a further detail, not only styles are broken when I load the home page, but also menu links now point to `http://localhost:8081/index.php/en/...page url...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the bottom of your configuration file:

```
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/
```

to

```
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://www.example.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com:8080/
```

also make sure you are requesting all your resources through http and not https, as you need a separate port for the two protocols.

This should fix it right away; but please consider setting up your containers to forward https traffic as well, and move your sites to https.

Also, these directives should be handled by mod_proxy and maybe your proxy isn't really working like you expect it to (it's doing a redirect instead of proxying), so the users see the 8081 port, which I think may be undesirable, so make sure this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

As below forward all trafic from `http` to `https`:
The container provides `http` to apache which then serves out the `https`
this will prevent the ports from being visible to the users and provide isolation for your container as long as the container is owned by a different uid than the forward facing web server.
The `ProxyPreserveHost` directive does what it is supposed to and presents the content without exposing ports etc.

```xml
    <VirtualHost 192.168.2.4:80>
       ServerName joomtest.mooo.com
       ProxyPreserveHost On

       ProxyPass / http://192.168**.3:8080/
       ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.**.3:8080/
       Redirect permanent / https://joomtest.mooo.com/
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost 192.168.2.4:443>
     ServerName joomtest.mooo.com
      ProxyPreserveHost On

      ProxyPass / http://192.168.2.3:8080/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.2.3:8080/
      ServerName joomtest.mooo.com
      ServerAdmin scauchon56@bell.net
      ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/joomtest.mooo.com.error.log
      CustomLog /var/log/apache2/joomtest.mooo.com.access.log combined
      SSLEngine On
      SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/joomtest.mooo.com/fullchain.pem
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/joomtest.mooo.com/privkey.pem  >
    </VirtualHost>
```